# Como funciona a rotação de Bits em C?

Tags: c

Gostaria de saber como funciona a rotação de bits, pois o conteúdo que consegui encontrar na internet não explica ao certo.

Obs.: A estrutura é a seguinte:

```
unsigned _rotl(unsigned valor,int conta); // deslocamento para a esquerda
unsigned _rotr(unsigned valor,int conta); // deslocamento para a direita
```

Sendo que conta representa o número de vezes para rotacionar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A rotação de bits é *semelhante* ao processo de deslocamento de bits.
Só que, nesse caso, você não "perde" os bits que extrapolam a dimensão da sua variável (o mais significativo ou o menos significativo, dependendo da direção da rotação). Esses bits são reposicionados na extremidade oposta. Ou seja, o mais significativo se torna o menos significativo ou o contrário, se a rotação for no sentido contrário. [Essa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aRotate_left.svg) imagem ilustra bem.

Por exemplo:

Supondo que `valor` seja:

```
valor = 1; // 0001  usando 4 bits para exemplo.
```

Se você rotacionar esse valor para direita:

```
O 1 foi para o início.
v
1000 // 1 vez
0100 // 2 vezes
0010 // 3 vezes
0001 // 4 vezes
```

Se você rotacionar esse valor para esquerda:

```
0010  // 1 vez
0100  // 2 vezes
1000  // 3 vezes
```

---

Isso defere do deslocamento de bits puro pois, comparando com a rotação para direita no primeiro caso, se você deslocasse para direita uma vez o resultado seria zero, pois ele acrescentaria um zero onde foi o 1.

Answer (score 8):

Esse texto da Wikipedia([`Circular Shift`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift) - Mudança Circular, *em tradução livre*) explica como é feito isso.

> Uma mudança circular é a operação de reorganizar as entradas em uma tupla , ou movendo-se da entrada final para a primeira posição, enquanto a mudança de todas as outras entradas para a posição seguinte, ou realizando a operação inversa. Uma mudança circular é um tipo especial de [ciclo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_%28mathematics%29) , o que por sua vez é um tipo especial de permutação.

A imagem abaixo ilustra isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### Exemplo

Se a sequência de bits `0001 0111` foram sujeitos a uma mudança circular de uma posição de bit:

Para a esquerda o resultado seria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para a direita o resultado seria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se a sequência de bits `0001 0111` foram sujeitos a uma mudança circular de 3 posições de bits:

- Para a esquerda é: `1011 1000`.
- Para a direita é: `1110 0010`.

Answer (score 2):

Rodando 8 bits para a esquerda
`00000111`
`00001110`
`00011100`
`00111000`
`01110000`
`11100000`
`11000001`
`10000011`

Rodando 8 bits para a direita
`00000111`
`10000011`
`11000001`
`11100000`
`01110000`
`00111000`
`00011100`
`00001110`
`00000111`